# How to set output location for Visual Studio scaffold generated files?

Tags: visual-studio, t4, scaffolding

Sorry if this has been asked but I can't find any documentation.  This is not a major problem just a little anoyance really.

I'm using the PM console to create a repository e.g.

PM> scaffold repository EventItem -DbContextType:SomeContext

The problem is the repository is then placed in the same location as the EventItem class.  Not a major prob as I can just move it but this is for efficiency.

Also anyone know a good source of documentation for using scaffold?  I couldn't find anything much explaining it.